# How to start Vagrant during startup/boot on Windows host?

Tags: windows, vagrant, startup, boot, autostart

I want to start a Vagrant VM (based on VirtualBox) after boot automatically. It has to work without any user to login but anyway if the Administrator user does a "vagrant status"/"vagrant ssh" it has to work properly.

So far I tried the following stuff:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run registry key (seems only to work on login)
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run registry key (seems only to work on login)
- "Task scheduler" (Vagrant VM is started but "vagrant status" returns that it is not running and login using "vagrant ssh" is not possible)
- Group policy scripts (Vagrant VM is started but "vagrant status" returns that it is not running and login using "vagrant ssh" is not possible)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is make it so the names of the VMs are predictable.  Here's the relevant portion portion I have in my `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.define "instancename" do |i|
  i.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.4"
  i.vm.host_name = "instancename"
  i.vm.network "public_network"
  i.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "instancename"
    v.linked_clone = true
  end
end
```

Then use [VBoxVmService](http://vboxvmservice.sourceforge.net/) to automatically start VMs.  You can install it via chocolatey as `choco install vboxvmservice`.  The configuration for the `Vagrantfile` above would be

```
[Vm1]
VmName=instancename
ShutdownMethod=savestate
AutoStart=yes
```

Comment: The linked vboxsvc is a service wrapper for Solaris, not for Windows